# ¿Cómo soluciono un error [Compile Error: Access level to AppBundle...] en un proyecto Symfony?

Tags: symfony3

estoy tratando de instalar un sitio que me dieron y cuando lo hago con la instalación de la base de datos y todo me sale el siguiente error

Compile Error: Access level to AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::json() must be protected (as in class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller) or weaker

alguien me podría ayudar
gracias

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que puedo apreciar de tu pregunta, lo más probable es que tengas declarada la función `json` como `private` en la clase `AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController`. Sucede que en la clase `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`, de la cual extienden todos los controladores de Symfony, ya existe una función con el nombre `json` y está declarada como protegida. Por lo tanto si tu intención es redefinir la función `json` en uno de tus controladores debe ser protegida o pública:

```
public function json(){...}
```

ó

```
protected function json(){...}
```

Por el contrario si la función `json` que está en tu controlador realiza determinada lógica que difiere a la de `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` entonces simplemente te recomiendo que le cambies el nombre a la función `json` y a todas las llamadas a la función en ese controlador.